# AndroidStudio builds in only one level of API

Tags: android-studio, sdk

So I bought a new laptop, installed the latest ver. of AndroidStudio (1.5.1) and have a new headache.  Even though I selected to build the APP in Lollipop (21) as the minimum version, it built it in 6.0.

And when I try to change that, in module settings, all the areas where I can change it are set to 6.0 and the dropdowns offer nothing else.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks ahead,

Sergio

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting confused.

As I understand it the minimum level is what is considered for being able to be run. However, the build is done utilising the latest/target SDK which supports the lower levels.

eq My minimum is 15. However target is 23.

So I think most have experienced this.

Comment: I believe you are correct and what happened was I never installed the lower SDKs, this was a fresh install